# symfony2 multiple database

Tags: symfony, parameters, fosuserbundle, multiple-databases

i use **symfony2** with **FOSuserBundle**.

i need 2 database connections
one for Usermanagement 
and another remote database connection.

how can i use them simultaneously?

can **parameters.ini** file have double database params?
sth like this

> [parameters]
>      database_driver="pdo_mysql"
>      database_host="localhost"
>      database_port=""
>      database_name="symfony"
>      database_user="root"
>      database_password=""
>      database2_driver="pdo_mysql"
>      database2_host="remote_ip"
>      database2_port=""
>      database2_name="symfonydb2"
>      database2_user="root"
>      database2_password=""

Comment: Did you check this link? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions:

> how can i use them simultaneously?

Like @vbergae said, just take a look at [How to work with Multiple Entity Managers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)

> can parameters.ini file have double database params?

For sure, you'll just have to reference in your config file it like this:

- %database2_driver%
- %database2_host%
- %database2_port%
- %database2_name%
- %database2_user%
- %database2_password%

Comment: i just want to use pure sql query how is it possible?

Comment: symfony2 being model agnostic you can use whatever you judge relevant to access you datas. But for separation concern leave your pure SQL queries in your model, don't do this in controller nor in views (Doh!)